# Add Web Reference Read and Generate Documentation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, soap, wsdl.exe

Is there a setting in Visual Studio 2010 that will generate comments for the generated proxy code?

For instance, I have a SOAP web service with the following:

```
<s:complexContent> -<s:extension base="s0:Criteria"> -<s:sequence> -<s:element name="GroupId" type="s:long" minOccurs="0"> -<s:annotation> <s:documentation>Unique group identifier. Can be used to get a specific group and/or a list of users for a group</s:documentation> </s:annotation> </s:element> -<s:element name="GroupName" type="s:string" minOccurs="0"> -<s:annotation> <s:documentation>Name of the group to find</s:documentation> </s:annotation> </s:element> </s:sequence> </s:extension> </s:complexContent> </s:complexType>
```

This contains **annotation** and **documentation** elements, however their content is not getting imported or used in Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASMX web services do not have this feature.

Note also that ASMX is a legacy technology, and that all new development should use WCF.